# Cannot open remote pdf using ICEpdf

Tags: java, icepdf

I am trying to display a remote pdf in JFrame using ICEpdf. I copied the code from their website to get started, which is:

```
import org.icepdf.ri.common.SwingViewBuilder;
import org.icepdf.ri.common.MyAnnotationCallback;

import javax.swing.*;
class ViewerComponentExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get a file from the command line to open
        String filePath = "http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf";

        // build a component controller
        SwingController controller = new SwingController();

        SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller);

        JPanel viewerComponentPanel = factory.buildViewerPanel();


        JFrame applicationFrame = new JFrame();
        applicationFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        applicationFrame.getContentPane().add(viewerComponentPanel);

        // Now that the GUI is all in place, we can try openning a PDF
        controller.openDocument(filePath);

        // show the component
        applicationFrame.pack();
        applicationFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ICEpdf could not open the specified file at http://www.icepdf.org/resources/DevelopersGuide.pdf. 
The file may be corrupted or not a supported file type.
```

I am using icepdf-core.jar and icepdf-viewer.jar. Do I need some other jar file to open a remote pdf? I am also unable to ask anything on their forum. I can't see any link to ask my own question there.

If someone has used this thing, please tell me how to resolve this error.

**EDIT**

I am able to open the remote file using the command `java org.icepdf.ri.viewer.Main -loadurl http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf` as stated in their docs, but it fails when I try to open it through the program.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okk. Getting no help. So I decided to do it by myself. You will not get it anywhere. Even in their documentation.
So this is what is need to be done to open a remote pdf file using icepdf.

```
try{URL url=new URL("http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf");
   controller.openDocument(url);
```

I realised that there are two overloading methods inside the SwingController class, one which takes a string as an arguement(for opening local pdf files) and another one for opening remote pdfs, which accepts a URL object.

Comment: The ICEpdf library is now being maintained at https://github.com/pcorless/icepdf .   If you have any trouble building the jars from source please create an issue.  Gradle and maven are supported.